# How can I get all .log and .txt files when I SSH into a server

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm using the Paramiko module to log into a server (ssh on some and sftp on others). I can get text and log files from specific folders on the server no problem. But there are many sub-directories that have .txt and .log files. I read some where that the get method will not accept (*.txt). Does anyone know a way around this. Here is the code that I'm currently using to log into a server and get a specific log:

```
 import paramiko
 import sys
 import os





 ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
 ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
 ssh.connect('10.5.48.74', username='root', password='******')

 ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
 ftp.get('/var/opt/crindbios/log/crindbios.log', '.')
 ftp.close()
```

Comment: why dont you use bash? find / -name *.txt | xargs ...

Comment: @dustyprogrammer ... yeah that would be nifty, but I'm adding this functionality to a Python gui app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Acquire a list of files with the following script. Then iterate over the list with ftp.get

```
import paramiko
import os

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('localhost',username='****')  

apath = '/var/log'
apattern = '"*.log"'
rawcommand = 'find {path} -name {pattern}'
command = rawcommand.format(path=apath, pattern=apattern)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
filelist = stdout.read().splitlines()

ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
for afile in filelist:
    (head, filename) = os.path.split(afile)
    print(filename)
    ftp.get(afile, './'+filename)
ftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

It is what dustyprogrammer proposed: On the remote server you apply shell commands to acquire the file list. Then you postprocess the list with python.

To download you have to create a new filepath for each file - download to directory as you proposed doesn't work (for me).

Comment: I'm running Python from a Windows 7 machine, and I'm having problem with downloading to the root as well. However, I can create a new folder ... Thanks!

Comment: Works great, I'm getting filename as a binary, not sure why...

Comment: Is there a way to get these files concurrently?

Answer (score 1):

The filenames are easy accessible via `sftp.listdir()`. Therefore, I do it this way

```
import os
import paramiko
rserver = "raspberrypi"
ruser = "pi"
rpassword ="<your-password>"
rdirectory_charging_log = "/home/pi/logs/"
directory_charging_log = "/Users/<your-user>/logs/"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() 
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
ssh.connect(rserver, username=ruser, password=rpassword)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
rfiles = sftp.listdir(rdirectory_charging_log)
rfile = ""
for rfile in rfiles: 
    sftp.get(rdirectory_charging_log+rfile, directory_charging_log+rfile)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```